# Code editor not recognizing modules recognized by shell

Tags: python, installation, module, path, sys

Windows 10, Python 3.8.5, using Mu 1.0.3. I am trying to install new modules. I just started learning python this weekend so I am pretty clueless. There does not seem to be much online that addresses this problem, unless I just don't know the right words.

I have tried going to command line and entering set `PYTHONPATH="[a list of all paths that came up in response to printing sys.path]"`. The command line seemed to accept this, since it did not give me an error message. But Mu still gives me a

```
ModuleNotFoundError: no module named "modulename".
```

I have additionally obtained just the location of the module by typing its name into the shell, and then attempting `sys.path.append("path")`, in both Mu and the shell. I get the same `ModuleNotFoundError`.

So, how do I get the code editor to find modules? And, how do I make it a permanent fix?

Comment: I believe [this article](https://automatetheboringstuff.com/2e/appendixa/) could help you, section **Installing Modules for the Mu Editor**.

Comment: I'll post it as an answer then.

Answer (score 0):

As per [this article](https://automatetheboringstuff.com/2e/appendixa/) *the Mu editor has its own Python environment, separate from the one that typical Python installations have*

Due to this, to be able to use them on Windows, we have to install our requirements into a specific location:

```
pip install –r automate-win-requirements.txt --target "C:\Users\USERNAME\AppData\Local\Mu\pkgs"
```